# SWIFT Can't Open Second URL in UIWebView with Second Button

Tags: swift, browser, uiwebview

Boy am I a noob. Can't get a button to open a second URL in SWIFT. App opens, loads URL in WebView upon open. Now I want a button to open another url in the WebView when clicked. (Back button, go forward button and reload no prob)... Please help, thank you

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

var URLPath = "http://bandersnatchorlando.com/x19559"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    loadAddressURL()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func loadAddressURL(){
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:URLPath)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL:
    requestURL)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}

@IBOutlet weak var reLoad: UIButton!
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the other button in your Storyboard and it is linked to an @IBAction then inside the action:

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://myotherurl.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```